Tesseract OCR fails to correctly recognize text in vehicle license plates
Question:
I am working on a project to detect and recognize vehicle license plates using YOLOv5, OpenCV, and Tesseract OCR. My script successfully detects the vehicle and isolates the license plate area, but the OCR results are inaccurate or fail to recognize the characters correctly.
Here is a brief overview of what my code does:
YOLOv5 Model: Detects the vehicle in the image.
License Plate Detection: Finds the license plate area within the detected vehicle.
Preprocessing: Enhances the license plate image using histogram equalization, Gaussian blur, and adaptive thresholding.
Character Segmentation: Segments the license plate image to isolate each character.
OCR Recognition: Uses Tesseract OCR to recognize each character.
Despite these preprocessing steps, the OCR results are often incorrect or incomplete.
# Load YOLOv5 model and detect objects
model, device = load_yolov5_model()
results = detect_objects(model, image, device)

# Find the license plate and preprocess the image
car_plate_boxes = find_license_plate_area(image, best_vehicle_box)
preprocessed_plate = preprocess_plate(plate_img)

# Segment and recognize characters
characters = segment_and_recognize_characters(preprocessed_plate)
plate_text = recognize_characters(characters)


Problem:
The OCR results are not reliable, even after applying preprocessing techniques like adaptive thresholding and morphological operations.
Steps I've Taken:
Adjusted the preprocessing parameters.
Experimented with different thresholding methods.
Adjusted the --psm setting in Tesseract.
Question:
What could be causing the OCR to fail in recognizing the text?
Are there any specific preprocessing techniques or adjustments I should try to improve the OCR accuracy for license plates?
Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
